# How can I change icicle-search-context-regexp variable in Emacs3 icicles

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, zsh, icicles

I'd like to use `icicle-comint-search` in `shell-mode`, but it used to be failed with error message like this

```
byte-code: No search contexts for `\^\[\^#\$%>
]\*\[#\$%>] \*\\S-\.\*'
```

Of course my shell prompt in `zsh` does not meet that regular expression. B

I tried to change `icicle-search-context-regexp` via `setq` to meet my `zsh` prompt. But when I issue `icicle-comint-search` the error message comes again. When I examine variable value of `icicle-search-context-regexp`, it was reset to its default value again.

How could I change it to meet my `zsh` prompt?

Answer (score 0):

`icicle-comint-search` uses this regexp: `(concat comint-prompt-regexp "\\S-.*")`.

So you can change the value of variable `comint-prompt-regexp` to change the search regexp.  You can set that variable in a mode hook, for example (e.g., `comint-mode-hook`).  Note that the doc string for `comint-prompt-regexp` says that it is used only if `comint-use-prompt-regexp` is non-`nil`, but for `icicle-comint-search` it is always used.  I've updated the `icicle-comint-search` doc string to mention `comint-prompt-regexp`.

Comment: My `zsh` prompt looks like this

`5 + 23:37:32 + ~/Shell/trunk^J-> `
I can match it in `isearch-forward-regexp` with this regexp `"^[0-9] \+ [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] \+ [~/].*^J->"`, and I can also match command line with by appending `\S-.*` to that regexp.

But when I set `comint-prompt-regexp` to that regexp, and run `icicle-comint-search` in `Shell-mode`, I still get error msg like this

`byte-code: No search contexts for `^[0-9] + [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] + [~/].*^J->\S-.*'`

Note: each `^J` represents a new line. I cannot type it in comment.

Comment: Note the difference between the two regexps you wrote: the second one uses `+` instead of `\+`. The problem is that you need to double backslashes in strings. And in Lisp code you need to double again. See the Elisp manual, node `Syntax for Strings`. See also node `Regexp Special`, the section about `\\`.